# drivers for HP ProBook 6460b

Tags: drivers, hp

I'm about to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my hp probook 6460b laptop, however, as I am completely wet behind my ears with this operating system I want to ask whether is there a website or anything from where I can download all the required drives for my hardware, let's say graphisc, wireless, bios etc., so that they comply with ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is NOT how Linux(/Ubuntu) works. We have generic drivers so we generally do not download drivers for our systems to get out systems installed.

In general: you start with a Live DVD, pick "try Ubuntu" and have a general assessment of what is working; if at this point something does not work. You can also set up your wireless at this point (if you do that you can use firefox -during- the installation to browse the web).

Then you choose the installer and have it install (partitioning, setting the username etc).

When this is done you log into your newly created system and will have a working system where the installation installed all drivers for all the hardware it detected.

All the 3rd party drivers are shown in a program called "additional drivers" and can be installed from there. These drivers are limited to your video card and optionally a wireless driver for cards that use a broadcom chip.

Comment: The good news is the answer is no.

Comment: ok one more thing. Currently I have 2 partitions on my hard drive "C" for Windows os and other software and D for other stuff say pics, music and so on. When installing Ubuntu I want 2 get rid of Windows totally but I'm not sure whether I shall erase both the C and D partitions, or will the wizard erase the C partition along with all the additional software installed on it and leave the D partition alone? Or do I have to set the hard drive to one single partition from the BIOS level prior to installing ubuntu?

Comment: Nope if you pick "erase all" or "replace windows by ubuntu" D: -WILL- get deleted. You need to pick "manual" and make sure to format your old C: and leave the old D: alone. By the way: using NTFS partiton with NO Windows install is bad; errors on the disk might need Windows tools. You are better off leaving Windows alone, make a dual boot, move the files from D: over to Windows and then delete both c: and d: and format them as ext.

Comment: thanks for that, it's working fine now. I have chosen the option with deletion of windows and replacement with ubuntu.

Comment: another thing is that I use microsoft word in my work and can't escape from this. I have installed it with the use of wine. Nevertheless, every time when I attempt to close the word window i get this notification: this function requires properly installed component MSXML 5.0. According to my reconing this is the type of library to select and load in wine settings. As I go to wine/cofiguration/libraries i get msxml, msxml2, msxml3, msxml4 and msxml6, no msxml5.0. Is there somethjing else I should ammend within wine to have word installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 6460b without discrete graphics and with Intel 6205 Wifi. Booting the live media in UEFI mode, everything worked out of the box, no additional drivers needed.

Comment: thanks, that's what I wanted to know. Funny thing but when you're new to sth obvious things may sometimes come harder than usual:)